# The Crashlytics dashboard is showing Crash-free statistics but there is no crash in the ISSUES table

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

The Crashlytics dashboard is showing Crash-free statistics but there is no crash in the ISSUES table.

Knowns:

1. Latest Fabric and Crashlytics following the Firebase tutorial
2. Forced a crash using `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()`
3. In `appdelegate` I set `FirebaseApp.configure()`
4. App is not on Appstore, but I uploaded the dsyms from the xarchive package

Comment: Do you reopen the app after it crashes?

Comment: Hi, yes, I did this several times. So I could see the crash-free statistics but no crash reports.

Comment: I'd suggest you write to support(at)fabric(dot)io with a link to this SO and they can help you resolve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

That can happen from time and here's why - when a session ends in a crash, the small amount of data that needs to be sent to know that the crash occurred can safely be sent. However, the crash report is larger, so it can't be sent safely until your users relaunch the app. Once your users do that, the crash report will be sent and you'll be able to dive into the details. Let me know if that clears it up or if you have any other questions!